# Uncaught ReferenceError function not defined for password and repassword

Tags: javascript, html

I have this error message below despite setting the javascript in the html. The code below is my html code for registration but none of the javascript function or event listener are working. I am still learning about javascript and html so please advice on what I did wrong.

Error message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: matchTest is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup
```

Register page

```
<div class="form">
        <form id="register-form" action="#">
          <ul class="form-container">
            <li>
              <h2>Create Account</h2>
            </li> 
            <li>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="name"
                name="name"     
                id="name"
                required />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="email" class="emailBox">Email</label>
              <input type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"  
                required          
                />
              <span class="emailText"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="password" class="passBox">Password</label>
              <input type="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                class="password"
                required        
                />
              <span class="passText"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="re-password">Re-Enter Password</label>
              <input type="password"
                id="re-password"
                name="re-password"
                class="re-password"
                onkeyup="matchTest()"
                required            
                />
            </li>
            <li>
              <button type="submit" class="primary">
                Register
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>Already have an account? <a href="/#/signin"> Sign-In </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

        window.onload = function() {
        let email = document.getElementById("email")
        let password = document.getElementById("password")
        
        
        email.addEventListener('input',()=>{
          let emailBox = document.querySelector('.emailBox')
          let emailText = document.querySelector('.emailText')
          const emailPattern = /[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$/
      
          if(email.value.match(emailPattern)){
            emailBox.classList.add('valid')
            emailBox.classList.remove('invalid')
            emailText.innerHTML = "Your Email Address in Valid"
          }else{
            emailBox.classList.add('invalid')
            emailBox.classList.remove('valid')
            emailText.innerHTML = "Must be a valid email address."
          }
         })
         
        password.addEventListener('input',()=>{
            let passBox = document.querySelector('.passBox');
            let passText = document.querySelector('.passText');
            const passPattern = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/;
      
            if(password.value.match(passPattern)){
               passBox.classList.add('valid');
               passBox.classList.remove('invalid');
               passText.innerHTML = "Your Password in Valid"; 
            }else{
               passBox.classList.add('invalid');
               passBox.classList.remove('valid');
               passText.innerHTML = "Your password must be at least 8 characters as well as contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, and one number."; 
          }
        })   
        function matchTest(){
          let password = document.querySelector('password').value
          let confirmPassword = document.querySelector('re-password').value
          
          if(password != confirmPassword)
            alert("Password don't match. Please try again.")
            return false
          }
          else if(password == confirmPassword){
            alert("Password match")
          }
        }
      }
      </script>    
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change following things:

- It is recommended to define `addEventListener` in JS not inline
  `repeatPassword.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => { matchTest(); });`
- Since you've defined the variable `password`, so it would be consistent to add `repeatPassword` also and get its value as `password.value` and `reapatPassword.value` in `matchTest`.
- It is recommended to use `===` instead of `==`.
- I've used `console.log` in place of `alert`. Since you are checking for password equality then it's annoying to get alert after every key press.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let email = document.getElementById("email");
  let password = document.getElementById("password");
  let repeatPassword = document.getElementById("re-password");

  email.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let emailBox = document.querySelector(".emailBox");
    let emailText = document.querySelector(".emailText");
    const emailPattern = /[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$/;

    if (email.value.match(emailPattern)) {
      emailBox.classList.add("valid");
      emailBox.classList.remove("invalid");
      emailText.innerHTML = "Your Email Address in Valid";
    } else {
      emailBox.classList.add("invalid");
      emailBox.classList.remove("valid");
      emailText.innerHTML = "Must be a valid email address.";
    }
  });

  password.addEventListener("input", () => {
    let passBox = document.querySelector(".passBox");
    let passText = document.querySelector(".passText");
    const passPattern = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/;

    if (password.value.match(passPattern)) {
      passBox.classList.add("valid");
      passBox.classList.remove("invalid");
      passText.innerHTML = "Your Password in Valid";
    } else {
      passBox.classList.add("invalid");
      passBox.classList.remove("valid");
      passText.innerHTML =
        "Your password must be at least 8 characters as well as contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, and one number.";
    }
  });

  function matchTest() {
    let pass = password.value;
    let confirmPass = repeatPassword.value;

    if (pass !== confirmPass) {
      console.log("Password don't match. Please try again.");
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("Password match");
    }
  }

  repeatPassword.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    matchTest();
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form id="register-form" action="#">
    <ul class="form-container">
      <li>
        <h2>Create Account</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" id="name" required />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="email" class="emailBox">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
        <span class="emailText"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="password" class="passBox">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="password" required />
        <span class="passText"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="re-password">Re-Enter Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="re-password" name="re-password" class="re-password" required />
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="submit" class="primary">
                            Register
                        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Already have an account? <a href="/#/signin"> Sign-In </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```